# Как сконфигурировать Jetpack Compose для сборки под desktop?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

Начал изучать Compose. При создании проекта в Андроид-студио - удается запустить проект на эмуляторе телефона. Но когда я пытаюсь запостить мейн-функцию по следующему примеру:

```
fun main() = application {
    Window(
        onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication,
        title = "Compose for Desktop",
        state = rememberWindowState(width = 300.dp, height = 300.dp)
    ) {
        val count = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
        MaterialTheme {
            Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp)) {
                Button(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
                    onClick = {
                        count.value++
                    }) {
                    Text(if (count.value == 0) "Hello World" else "Clicked ${count.value}!")
                }
                Button(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
                    onClick = {
                        count.value = 0
                    }) {
                    Text("Reset")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибки следующие

[image: Errors]

Application система не находит. В android и androidx ничего подобного нет. Как настроить сборку программы под ПК? Где найти потерянные элементы?

Answer (score 0):

Функции `Window()` и `application()` определены в библиотеке `ui-desktop`, которую можно подключить в проект таким способом:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.compose.ui:ui-desktop:1.4.0'
```

Либо таким способом:

```kotlin
implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
```

Чтобы лучше разобраться, как настроить сборку compose-проекта для desktop, посмотрите как это сделано [в демо-проекте](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform-desktop-template/blob/main/build.gradle.kts) на официальном гитхабе JetBrains.